# gx:Track updates and time slider in Google Earth Plugin

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

My goal is to periodically update a position of a track, rendered in Google Earth Plugin. I am using a GWT-based web app and a servlet that produces KML updates.  First I create a Placemark with a `<gx:Track/>` and a specific ID, then I push `<Create/>` elements with new `<when/>` and `<gx:coord/>` - similar to how it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613376/kml-gxtrack-network-link-updates). The updates are fetched by GE plugin and I see that the time slider is updated - the time span is longer each time an update occurs. However, GE does not show the latest position, I have to move the slider manually to see the most recent position. Is there a way to force GE to do it automatically? I was thinking of using `<gx:Multitrack/>`, but then read somewhere that it's not supported by the plugin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.. I wish there was more documentation on using NetworkLinkControl updates with `<gx:Track/>`, but all I've been able to find are random forum posts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you also update the time using something like this

```
        var newTime = // the time/date of the update
        var timeStamp = ge.createTimeStamp('');
        timeStamp.getWhen().set(newTime);
        ge.getTime().setTimePrimitive(timeStamp);
```